# no viable alternative at character '\'

Tags: apex, soql, query, error, dynamic-soql

When I run the below code, I get this error:

> no viable alternative at character '\'

Code:

```
public void getChildRecords() {
    DescribeSObjectResult describe = objectVar.getSObjectType().getDescribe();

    childRelationshipNames = new List<String>();

    for (Schema.ChildRelationship child:describe.getChildRelationships()) {
        childRelationshipNames.add(child.getRelationshipName());
    }

    String relationshipQuery = 'SELECT ';

    for (String relationship:childRelationshipNames) {
        if (relationship != 'null' && relationship != null) { 
            relationshipQuery += '(SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Email, Salary__c FROM ' + relationship + '), ';
        }
    }

    relationshipQuery += 'Id,  FirstName, LastName, Email, Salary__c FROM ' + describe.getName() + ' WHERE ID = \'' + objectVar.Id + \'' ';

    objectVar = Database.query(relationshipQuery);
}
```

Comment: You need to do this `Id = \'' + objectVar.Id +'\''`

Comment: You can use bind in dynamic query so you should only need ' where Id = :objectvar.id '

Comment: @Eric - No dot notation in dynamic binds - `:objectId` works but `object.id` won't. see https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm?search_text=bind

Comment: Personally I'd stick to the `:` notation and just have a local ID type variable equal to `objectVar.Id`. Easier to type correctly and read and a habit that avoids injection attack risk for cases where that could arise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you've escaped the wrong single quote.

**Incorrect**

```
'WHERE Id = \'' + someId + \'' '
```

**Correct**

```
'WHERE Id = \'' + someId + '\''
```

Also noted in the comments, you can use bind variables if you cache the Id itself as a top level property.

```
Id someId = objectVar.Id;
objectVar = Database.query('SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE Id = :someId');
```